# Showing deformation retract : $B^3 \setminus T^2$, $R^3 \setminus S^1$, $S^2 \bigvee S^1$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Here what i want to show is 
$B^3 \setminus T^2$, $R^3 \setminus S^1$, $S^2 \bigvee S^1$, $i.e$, three spaces are deformation retract to each other.

Can you give me some hints or concept(?) geometric way to show this?

I found some relevant materials on online.  see
[problem-6](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~lauda/teaching/540-Fall-13/HW3-solutions.pdf).

Ah, my question might be wrong. I should say $S^1$ is embedded in $R^3$
Taking A to be the embedding of $S^1$ in $R^3$ and $X = R^3-A$, X is deformation retractable. As stated in problem 6.

Comment: 1) You want \vee, not \wedge. 2) As stated, this is false. First, none of these spaces live in the other, so you can't say they deformation retract onto one another. Second, much worse, none of these spaces are actually homotopy equivalent.

Comment: @MikeMiller, Really? The above things comes from computing fundamental groups of $R^3 - S^1$ in my math class, i tried to find out references but i couldn't so i made a post here.

Comment: This is correct if you mean completely different things than what's written. 1) You mean $\setminus$, not $/$ - the latter means quotient. 2) You mean the *solid torus* when you write $T^2$. 3) As mentioned in the first comment, you mean $S^2 \vee S^1$.

Comment: @MikeMiller, You are right. I just correct the question properly